Wie lautet die richtige Betonung für "sodass/so dass" oder gibt es überhaupt eine?
Zum Beispiel im Satz: "So dass er entfliehen konnte"
Wenn man hier die Betonung betrachten will, scheint mir beides korrekt zu sein:
So dass er entfliehen konnte (drei Hebungen)
bzw
So dass er entfliehen konnte (vier Hebungen)
Also im Gesprochenen halte ich vom Gefühl her beides für richtig. Gibt es hier aber eine objektive Antwort, woraus folgen würde, dass einer der beiden eigentlich falsch ist?

Ich sehe keinen Fall, wo "so dass" korrekt wäre. Es müsste dann doch immer "so, dass" heißen, wie es auch Björn in seiner Antwort benutzt.

Es gibt nicht nur einen Unterschied in der Betonung, sondern auch in der Bedeutung.
… so, dass …

Er öffnete das Fenster so, dass er entfliehen konnte.
 = Er öffnete das Fenster auf eine Weise, dass er entfliehen konnte.

…, sodass …

Er öffnete das Fenster, sodass er entfliehen konnte.
 = Er öffnete das Fenster, um entfliehen zu können.


Und das ist die Regel? "Sodass" wird immer auf die zweite Silbe betont?

Ja. „IPA: [zoˈdas]“. Siehe zum Beispiel https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/sodass.

Wer will, kann's ja auch »so dass« schreiben.
